# Is T Min(T, T); always better than const T& Min(const T&, const T&); if sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*)?

Tags: c++, performance, templates, overloading, overload-resolution

```
template<class T>
T Min(T a, T b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

template<class T>
const T& Min(const &T a, const T& b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

Which is better? Or, should I redefine the template function as follows:

```
template<class T, ENABLE_IF(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*))>
T Min(T a, T b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

template<class T, ENABLE_IF(sizeof(T) > sizeof(void*))>
const T& Min(const &T a, const T& b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

// Note: ENABLE_IF is a helper macro.
```

Comment: I feel that any question asking what is better should include a precise definition of "better".

Comment: RVO would take care of it anyway, would it not?

Comment: My guess is such a small function will be inlined anyway, so no passing actually happens, be it by value or pointer.

Comment: The even better solution: `std:min<T>`, the compiler writer knows these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but given that

```
template<class T>
const T& Min(const &T a, const T& b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

..is basically replaced with (lets say for T = bool):

```
const bool & Min(const bool & a, const bool & b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

I would say it is a fair assumption that the compiler would pass the bool in the most efficient way possible. I.E, just because we're using & doesn't mean that it *has* to be passed by reference.

Another couple of ideas:
When a function is called, arguments are either pushed onto the stack, or they're passed via a register. The only way that

```
bool Min(bool a, bool b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

would be "better"/"faster" than

```
const bool & Min(const bool & a, const bool & b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
```

is if passing a `bool` was faster than passing a `const bool &` (Ignoring dereferencing at the start of the function). I can't see this being true, since unless its being pushed onto the stack (depends on your calling convention), registers are all at least the size of a pointer on the host architecture. (I.E, rax is 64-bit, eax is 32-bit)

Further, I presume it would be easier for the compiler to inline, since (just from the function signature) we can be guaranteed that the function never locally modifies the values of `a` and `b`, and thus needs no space for them.

For user defined types, there are two cases.

1. The type fits in a register, and we can treat it just like a basic type.
2. The type does not fit in a register and must be passed by reference (if we use `const & T`) or as a copy (if we use just `T`). Since copying a class invokes class constructors, `const & T` will probably be faster in every case.

But, I'm really just speculating here. To check if there is a difference in `bool` vs `const bool &`, the best way would be to check for your specific compiler by outputting assembly and seeing if there is any difference.

HTH.

Comment: What if T is a user defined class?

Comment: Then if it cannot entirely fit in a register, it will need to be passed by reference.

Comment: Don't you think you should specifically include the case in your answer? It is known that basic types are faster to pass by value. Most of the time the real trouble is the user defined types that cause this type of consideration when templates are concerned.

Comment: OK Then! WHY DO COMMENTS HAVE TO BE AT LEAST 15 CHARACTERS IN LENGTH ARRGH.

Comment: "I.E, just because we're using & doesn't mean that its being passed by reference (since we have const too)." -- `const` doesn't mean that the value won't change. It doesn't even mean that the value won't be changed by the function. The fact that you're using `&` does mean that it's being passed by reference (unless the function gets inlined, as you noted).

Comment: For example, `int i; void f(const int&r) { int a = r; ++i; int b = r; assert(a != b); }` is valid and must not fail the assertion when calling `f(i)`. Even worse, a function is permitted to cast away the `const` (in ways that the caller cannot possibly see) and modify the referenced object, so long as it wasn't *defined* with `const`. There's no rule that says that's invalid, so it's valid.

Comment: @hvd Good point! Another good example would be multi-threaded applications (which could change the argument whilst the function is being called), or mutable values in classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have seen g++ do this automatically when optimising: it can generate a version of `Min` taking arguments by value when it can tell that this is more efficient and wouldn't violate the *as if* rule (which I think basically means small types with trivial copy constructors).

I have no idea what the name of this optimisation is or whether other compilers implement it however.

---

As an aside, I wonder if you can get the best of both worlds in C++11:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto Min(T&& l, U&& r) -> decltype(l < r ? l : r)
{
    return l < r ? l : r;
}
```

If my understanding of "universal references" is correct, this should never be less efficient than using lvalue references as in your example, and possibly more efficient if `l` or `r` are rvalues (such as integer literals). As an added bonus, you get to compare things of different types where this makes sense (`int` vs `long` or what-have-you).